# Reputation not changing real time on top-bar

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, top-bar

I am seeing two different *Reputation* on different page after waiting 5 mins on the same page. The window which has focus is the window where I am seeing wrong *reputation*.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK if the reputation is decreased, the reputation on the topbar is not updated automatically (unlike when the reputation is increased). We have to refresh the page to see the updated reputation. So it's by design IMO.

Comment: Yep. We only real-time positive reputation changes.